# Objective c missing context for method declaration

Tags: objective-c, methods, method-call

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
 {
     @selector(grades);

 }

-(int)grades:(int)grade{
    printf("Please write down your grade:");  
    scanf("%d", &grade);/*the grade value written has assigned to grade parameter*/   
    printf("\n");

    if((grade > 100) || (grade <0)){/*This is a warning range of grades */
    printf("Warning!!\nYour grade is out of range\nPlease write a NUMBER between 0-100\n");
}
else{/*The grade ranges are defined*/
    if((0<=grade) && (grade<=20))
        NSLog(@"Your letter grade is : F\nyou failed\n");/*NSLog has been used insted of printf*/
    if((21<=grade) &&(grade<=40))
        NSLog(@"Your letter grade is : D\nTry again\n");
    if((41<=grade) && (grade<=60))
        NSLog(@"your letter grade is : C\nNot bad\n");
    if((61<=grade)&&(grade<=80))
        NSLog(@"Your letter grade is : B\nWell Done\n");
    if((81<=grade)&&(grade<=100))
        NSLog(@"your letter grade is : A\nGreat !!\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

I am having a problem in method declaration I guess I checked for it but 
I couldn't find anything wrong
If any of you can help me it would be great.
Thank you

Comment: What does the `@selector(grades)`? Plus, shouldn't it be `@selector(grades:)`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `@selector(grades);` doesn't do anything

Comment: It needs to compile the code blocks inside the grades method

Comment: you must be getting a warning Expression result unused for it. explain you question, what you are trying to do here.

Comment: In the main function I tried to call the method grades bur I couldn't accomplish

Comment: My aim is to get an input from the user and responding it with a grade.But I want to do it by using a method because I am trying to learn using objective c methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no context for the method. The method is declared as instance method `-` for an object, however there is no class associated with it. So In what context the method is to be declared is unknown.

For your case use,

```
            int grade (int grade)
            {
                printf("Please write down your grade:");
                scanf("%d", &grade);/*the grade value written has assigned to grade parameter*/
                printf("\n");

                if((grade > 100) || (grade <0)){/*This is a warning range of grades */
                    printf("Warning!!\nYour grade is out of range\nPlease write a NUMBER between 0-100\n");
                }
                else{/*The grade ranges are defined*/
                    if((0<=grade) && (grade<=20))
                        NSLog(@"Your letter grade is : F\nyou failed\n");/*NSLog has been used insted of printf*/
                    if((21<=grade) &&(grade<=40))
                        NSLog(@"Your letter grade is : D\nTry again\n");
                    if((41<=grade) && (grade<=60))
                        NSLog(@"your letter grade is : C\nNot bad\n");
                    if((61<=grade)&&(grade<=80))
                        NSLog(@"Your letter grade is : B\nWell Done\n");
                    if((81<=grade)&&(grade<=100))
                        NSLog(@"your letter grade is : A\nGreat !!\n");
                }
                return 0;
            }

            int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
            {

                grade(0);
            }
```

Comment: Well indeed this is the one I achieved but is it an objective c method?

Comment: Its just a C Method. For Objective C, Declare a class and declare your method `grade` within the class. Then in  main, instantiate the object and call this method.

Answer (score 1):

I have an impression that the issue of "**Missing context for method declaration"(MCFMD)** has **never** been fully understood.

Relevant posts offer some solutions for some specific case, but not any explanation or general approach that could work in 90% of cases at least, e.g.

> **Q:** objective-c "*Missing context for method declaration*" -- asked May 13 by user3631024
>
> **Q:** “*Missing Context for method declaration with the constructor*" -- asked sep 18 by user2789992
>
> **Q:** “*Missing context for method declaration*” *for overridden description method* -asked apr 26 '12 by pdenlinger

Meanwhile, a few guys complain that they believe that MCFMD issue has come of age and was adequately addressed... I was fighting with 33 MCFMD in my code at one moment and this was more like shooting in the dark. I wish those who have more understanding of the MCFMD issue share their valuable knowledge or anything towards the understanding... **Thanks a lot for paying attention!**